# json.load() not reading data from connected socket?

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

in the following code i want to establish a connection to a socket and then write certain json string and then read it through makefile. the writing part is working fine but in the reading part, **the code is unable to load the json string?** in the below code, the code gets stuck at this line `conn_data = json.load(in_file)`.

**Client Socket**

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

            # connect to directory server - runs on port 9001
            self.dir_host = 'localhost'  # directory server address
            self.dir_port = 9001         # directory server port

            conn_str = json.dumps({'command':'register','role':role})
            print "to be sent: ", conn_str

            s.connect((self.dir_host, self.dir_port))
            s.sendall(conn_str)  # send test string
            print "sent the bloody string chars: "
    #        s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
            print "shutdown socket for writing now going into recieve part (should be a loop right)"


            in_file = s.makefile('r',0)     # open the socket as a file object, read-only, unbuffered
            print "open socket"
            conn_data = json.load(in_file)  # we expect a json string so load as dict object
            print conn_data
```

**Server Socket**

```
def start(self):
        #create an INET, STREAMing socket
        serv_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        serv_sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        serv_sock.listen(5) # and listen for connections

        while (1):
            print "listening ... "
            cli_sock, addr = serv_sock.accept()
            print "recieved connection from {0}", addr 
            self.handle_connection(cli_sock)
            print "handle running"


    def handle_connection(self, in_sock):
        in_file = in_sock.makefile('r',0) # open the socket as a file object, read-only, unbuffered
        cli_data = json.load(in_file) #

        print "read the request into json object for the connection ...", cli_data

        role = int(cli_data['role'])

        if cli_data['command'] == 'register':
            role_count = self.get_role_count(role)
            proc_num = str(role) + '.' + str(role_count)
            port = self.maxPort
            # now add the stuff to the process table
            self.PaxosProcs[role].append(self.PaxosProcess(proc_num, port))
            # get the info that the requesting process needs
            conn_data = self.get_connection_data(role)
            conn_data['proc_num'] = proc_num
            conn_data['port'] = port
            conn_info = json.dumps(conn_data)

            self.maxPort += 1
            self.increment_role_count(role)

        elif cli_data['command'] == 'update':
            # if proc is not in the table tell it to register by returning an error
            proc_num = cli_data['proc_num']

            if self.is_registered(proc_num, role):
                conn_info = json.dumps(self.get_connection_data(role))
            else:
                conn_info = json.dumps({'error':'unregistered'})

        elif cli_data['command'] == 'remove':
            proc_num = cli_data['proc_num']
            if self.remove(proc_num, role):
                conn_info = json.dumps({'info':'removed'})
            else:
                conn_info = json.dumps({'error':'unregistered'})

        in_sock.sendall(conn_info)
        print "result dispatched..."
        in_file.close()
        in_sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        in_sock.close()
```

Comment: Do you have a simple echo server? What is on the other side of the socket?

Comment: @kshikama yes i have a simple server. it shows me before it starts dumping json that it has received the connection from a particular ip address

Comment: So does the server echo the test string back? Unless the server sends something, you will receive nothing on your read side. Can you post the simple server code?

Comment: @kshikama no it does not echoes the test string back. i have pasted the server socket code in the question. currently it stops in the while loop after printing **received connection from**.

Comment: Stops? So there is no error message?

Comment: Otherwise can you add a `print conn_info` message before your `in_sock.sendall(conn_info)`? I suspect that you are sending back nothing.

Comment: @kshikama so i played around with some print statements on both client and server side and realized that whenever it encounters `json.load` the console keeps on running for a very long time however there are no errors. is this normal? i added a print statement after `json.load` but i cannot see it. seems it gets hanged at load function.